# Passing a string from android to wcf restful service is getting null

Tags: android, rest, wcf, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-starting-guide

Am having a wcf webservice, when am hitting the webservice in POST menthod from android, the value which am getting in service is null.

The cs file is given below:

> `[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
>   string Login(Student Student);
>     public class Student
>       {
>           [DataMember(Name = "image")]
>           public string image
>           {
>               get;
>               set;
>           }
>      }`

The configuration file is given below

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">   </defaultProxy>   
</system.net>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />

</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>

  <service name="ESIService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ESIService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>

 </service>
</services>


<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior  name="ServiceBehaviour">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="41" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
</system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Service1.svc" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

The svc file is given below, when am running am getting id value as null.

> `public string Login(Student Student)
>           {
>               String id = Student.image;}`

The Android code is given below:

```
JSONStringer item = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                .key("Student")
                .object()
                .key("image").value("abcd")
                .endObject()
                .endObject();
```

URL am hitting is .../Login

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with android develeopment, but since you have BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, the service is expecting the following json string in the request body:

{"image":"abcd"}

Perhaps this would work:

```
JSONStringer item = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                .key("image").value("abcd")
                .endObject();
```